# Resizing height of formsheet presentation on an iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

By using UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate, I was able to get a view controller presented in the style of form sheet.

Setting the preferredContentSize can change the width of the vc but not the height, why?

[screenshot of preferredContentSize set to (200,200)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXwz8.png)